# The struts actions called twice

Tags: java, struts

I'm using struts 1.1 and my strut actions are called twice every time I made a single request.
I don't have submit button in the jsp page. Form submission is done by jquery. Is it because of my computer ?

Any kind help is appreciated.

Comment: A little more detail including configuration will help people to answer your question. The problem you stated here is too vague.

Answer (score 2):

Use a tool like **Firebug** (Firefox extension) or **Live Http Headers** and check the HTTP requests the browser is sending to the server. There may be some `javascript` or `meta-refresh` tags somewhere generating multiple requests to the same resource?

EDIT: Also check, there is a possibility of looping due to misconfigured redirects/forwards  in your JSP/action e.g. page1 -> page2  -> page1.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem a while a go. But I've figured it out that in my `web.xml` I had:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

Load on startup element was set to 2:

```
<load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
```

So I've made it to be set to 1:

```
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

And it solved my problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Paulius, I check it and it is set to 1. Still having the same problem.

Comment: `load-on-startup` affects Servlet load order by the container when the web application is being deployed. It does not affect the request processing as OP is facing.